# Export 2D javascript array to Excel sheet

Tags: javascript, html, excel, export-to-excel, window.open

I know, there are hundreds of questions on this topic on here, but I still could not find satisfactory answers after a day of searching:

I have a 2D javascript array, which I want to download as an Excel sheet.

Here is a fiddle with the code I got so far:

https://jsfiddle.net/3an24jmw/7/

The download works, but there are several issues, which I could not solve after days of trying:

1. All items end up in the first column of the Excel sheet, because Excel interprets the "," separating the elements as part of the data. How can I separate the elements in a way Excel understands?
2. The file name is some cryptic code. How can I set the file name?
3. The downloaded file has a double `.xls` ending (`.xls.xls`). How can get a single `.xls` ending?
4. Excel tells me every time the file could be corrupted or unsafe. How do I prevent this?

Any help for any of these questions would be appreciated.

```
exportToCsv = function() {
    var CsvString = "";
    Results.forEach(function(RowItem, RowIndex) {
        RowItem.forEach(function(ColItem, ColIndex) {
            CsvString += ColItem + ',';
        });

        CsvString += "\r\n";
    });

    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(CsvString));
}
```

**UPDATE**

I just found out by chance, that 1. 2. and 4. can be solved by replacing `vnd.ms-excel` with `csv`.

The file will not be `.xls` anymore, but the csv can be opened by Excel without problems and behaves like intended.

Only problem remaining is the file name!

**UPDATE 2**

Finally after 2 full workdays of searching and trying, I found the solution, which I would like to share here, to help anybody with the same problem:

Simply include an invisible `<a>` element, which defines the file an useful name using its `download="somedata.csv"` attribute.

Here is my final and fully functional fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/3an24jmw/25/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Finaly after 2 full workdays of searching and trying, I found the solution, which I would like to share here, to help anybody with the same problem:

Simply include an invisible element, which gives the file an usefull name using its download="somedata.csv" attribute:

Here is my final and fully functional fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/3an24jmw/25/

```
var Results = [
["Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4"],
["Data", 50, 100, 500],
["Data", -100, 20, 100],
];

exportToCsv = function() {
  var CsvString = "";
  Results.forEach(function(RowItem, RowIndex) {
    RowItem.forEach(function(ColItem, ColIndex) {
      CsvString += ColItem + ',';
    });
    CsvString += "\r\n";
  });
  CsvString = "data:application/csv," + encodeURIComponent(CsvString);
  var x = document.createElement("A");
  x.setAttribute("href", CsvString );
  x.setAttribute("download","somedata.csv");
  document.body.appendChild(x);
  x.click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The separator Excel expects for csv depends on your system locale setting for list separator. 
You can hint Excel which separator to use for your csv file by adding `"sep=,"` as the first line. 
In your case use could use: `var CsvString = '"sep=,"\r\n';`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but did that work for you in the fiddle ?
When I try it, the first row of the sheet is replaced by sep=,

Comment: My bad, misplaced the double quote. Now fixed.

Answer (score -1):

https://github.com/shuchkin/simplexlsxgen#js-array-to-excel-ajax

```php
<?php // array2excel.php
if (isset($_POST['array2excel'])) {
    require __DIR__.'/simplexlsxgen/src/SimpleXLSXGen.php';
    $data = json_decode($_POST['array2excel'], false);
    \Shuchkin\SimpleXLSXGen::fromArray($data)->downloadAs('file.xlsx');
    return;
}
?>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>JS array to Excel</title>
</head>
<script>

function array2excel() {
    var books = [
        ["ISBN", "title", "author", "publisher", "ctry"],
        [618260307, "The Hobbit", "J. R. R. Tolkien", "Houghton Mifflin", "USA"],
        [908606664, "Slinky Malinki", "Lynley Dodd", "Mallinson Rendel", "NZ"]
    ];
    var json = JSON.stringify(books);

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.onload = function () {
        if (this.status === 200) {
            var file = new Blob([this.response], {type: this.getResponseHeader('Content-Type')});
            var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
            var filename = "", m;
            var disposition = this.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
            if (disposition && (m = /"([^"]+)"/.exec(disposition)) !== null) {
                filename = m[1];
            }
            var a = document.createElement("a");
            if (typeof a.download === 'undefined') {
                window.location = fileURL;
            } else {
                a.href = fileURL;
                a.download = filename;
                document.body.appendChild(a);
                a.click();
            }
        } else {
            alert("Error: " + this.status + "  " + this.statusText);
        }
    }
    
    request.open('POST', "array2excel.php");
    request.responseType = "blob";
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.send("array2excel=" + encodeURIComponent(json));
}
</script>
<body>
<input type="button" onclick="array2excel()" value="array2excel" />
</body>
</html>
```