# Vue generate and download excel file

Tags: javascript, excel, vue.js

Is there any way i can generate an **excel** file programmatically using an array, and then allow the user to download it on an event fired?

I have seen this done in javascript by creating a href tag with the download attr programmatically, but this isn't usually the approach of vue.

*Template*

```html
<template>
  <button @click="toExcel">Download</button>
</template>

<script>
data(){
  return{
    someArray: [1,2,3]
  }
},

methods: {
  toExcel() {
    //code to export excel
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Which format do you need exactly - a `.xlsx` file (standard Excel file) or a CSV file? There are various libraries like [zipcelx](https://github.com/egeriis/zipcelx) and [SheetJS](https://sheetjs.com/demo) that you could use for `.xlsx` files generation. If you are looking for CSV file generation, you could refer to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45611674/export-2d-javascript-array-to-excel-sheet)

Comment: @TKD21 Any format would be good for me. I saw that answer, but that's not the normal approach in vue, you don't normally create a tag in the javascript code. Though if that's the only way of doing it well that's another matter.

Comment: In your question, you say "on event fired". Which event are you planning to use? If I understand correctly, you need a CSV file generated when something happens. You can reuse the code from the solution I linked but instead of appending the encoded URI string to a tag, you should just open a new tab through JS with that URI string loaded in that new tab. The problem with that is that the downloaded file will not have any file extension, as the `download` attribute that is usually taken from an `<a>` tag is missing.

Comment: @TKD21 a click, am planning on using a button. The user click this button i give him the file.

Comment: Okay, so now you have two options to do this: Wrap your `<button>` in a `<a>` tag and add the `download` attribute to your anchor tag OR replace your `<button>` tag with a `<a>` tag and apply some CSS to make that look like a button (personally, I recommend using Vuetify or Bootstrap for this). Your `toExcel()` function will be converting the array data to a CSV file (like the code in the example) and setting the `href` attribute of your `<a>` tag to the data URI you need to download the file.