# KTDatatable does not export data to pdf,excel,csv files

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

[image]the code :

datatable = $('#kt_datatable').KTDatatable({

```
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copyHtml5',
            'excelHtml5',
            'csvHtml5',
            'pdfHtml5'
        ],
```

Comment: And when choosing from the export list and then pressing does not respond and is redirected to # url

Comment: I have the same exact problem !! but I can't figure it out ! did you try also this: `buttons: [  'print', 'copy',  'excel', 'csv',  'pdf'  ],` @bassel also if you open the console command in chrome and go in console and then click the option (es. pdf), what error do you get ?

Answer (score 0):

KTDatatable does not support the export feature. But you can use this plugin to export as a PDF. Integrate it to your custom export button, by passing the data into the PDF plugin. https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable

```
var data = datatable.getDataSet();
```

Call this function to get the current data in the grid.

I would suggest CSV more than excel, and I think the easier one is to create a CSV file.
You can also learn more about CSV text format here;

[Export 2D javascript array to Excel sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45611674/export-2d-javascript-array-to-excel-sheethttps://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001356.htm)